# Karabiner: how to prevent Shift+Alt from being sent?

Tags: windows, macos, keyboard, remote-desktop

Can Karabiner's JSON configuration indicate that Shift+Alt should not be sent when typing Shift+Alt+other_key?

The use case is as follows, from inside Microsoft Remote Desktop connected to Windows:

- Let's say I want to type Shift+Alt+) and insert "]" in the Windows app (as is usual with the French keyboard).
- Now, when I start by typing Shift+Alt, *Windows switches keyboard layouts*. I want to keep this feature on the remote machine, but it should not interfere with Shift+Alt+other_key combinations.

Thus, I would like to produce "]" on the Windows remote machine when I type Shift+Alt+), without Shift+Alt switching between keyboard layouts.

It is not obvious that this could work, as Shift+Alt must be pressed first, which might necessarily trigger the keyboard layout switching. However, things could in principle work if Karabiner would not send anything to Windows when Shift+Alt is pressed, and then only send either "]" if ")" is pressed, or activate the layout switching when Shift+Alt is *released*.

My current configuration for having Shift+Alt+) produce "]" in Microsoft Remote Desktop (from a French-keyboard MacBook) is:

```
{
    "conditions": [
        {
            "bundle_identifiers": [
                "com\\.microsoft\\.rdc\\.(mac|osx|macos)"
            ],
            "type": "frontmost_application_if"
        }
    ],
    "from": {
        "key_code": "hyphen",
        "modifiers": {
            "mandatory": [
                "option",
                "shift"
            ]
        }
    },
    "to": [
        {
            "key_code": "close_bracket"
        }
    ],
    "type": "basic"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure Windows, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> by itself does nothing
as long as you keep pressing both keys. It will only take effect when the keys
are freed. Therefore I find it hard to understand why you have an immediate
action when you only press the keys (but then I'm not on the Mac).

A possible solution would be to use on Windows the keyboard remapper
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following AutoHotkey script might block <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>
by itself, but will convert <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>(</kbd>
to <kbd>]</kbd>. It worked for me on English Windows 10, and should also work
in your environment.

```
!Shift::return
!+):: Send, ]
```

It might be worth testing if the script can work without the last line.

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

AutoHotkey references:

- [Remapping Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm)
- [Hotkeys - Definition & Usage](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)
- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Send Keys & Clicks](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm)

Comment: Note that your mappings in Karabiner might conflict with the above.

Comment: Interesting, about Shift-Alt working upon release on Windows. I'm guessing that Karabiner someho does send the key releases instead of sending the release of the bracket only? Unfortunately I cannot install AutoHotKey on the remote PC, as it is administered by the IT department.

Comment: AutoHotKey has a portable version without installation.

Comment: That's good. However, I use Shift-Alt constantly on the Windows machine, so I cannot deactivate it. If I remember correctly, another option is to ask Windows 7 for a different keyboard-switching key combo, but then other people will be surprised when they use my machine. That's why I was hoping that Karabiner could somehow handle this.

Comment: Using AutoHotKey, another possibility would be to assign another shortcut for switching languages.

Comment: It’s built in Windows 7 already (Control Panel > Change Keyboard… > Change Keyboard > Advanced Key Settings).

Comment: Would you consider this as s solution to the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not, because this would be misleading for readers, as the question is really about "how to prevent Shift+Alt from being sent" by the Mac while "keeping [Shift+Alt for switching between keyboards] on the [Windows] machine"…

Comment: The post can be modified. The question is whether this *helps you*.

Comment: It does in the sense that I now wonder whether the initial question does have an answer, and it doesn't in that I already had a simpler solution than what this answer proposes (see my comment above on the solution built in Windows 7).

Comment: "Change Keyboard" seems to be some application that is installed on your computer. The standard way is *Control Panel > Region and Language > Keyboards and Languages > Change keyboards... > Advanced Key Settings > Between input languages > Change Key Sequence...*